# Why google retail search api not return production infos, ex: title, description, etc ? thanks

Tags: google-api, google-api-client

I try to test API google retail with your tools online, but I can not see any product infos, ex: title, price, image link, etc...

url test online: https://cloud.google.com/retail/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.locations.catalogs.placements/search

Anyone know why ? and how to fix it ? thanks very much

request image:

[image]

result data return, you can find id and product name, product variants, that's all:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "id": "005013199",
      "product": {
        "name": "projects/100575538996/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/branches/0/products/005013199",
        "variants": [
          {
            "name": "projects/100575538996/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/branches/0/products/829241429175635296",
            "id": "829241429175635296",
            "type": "VARIANT",
            "colorInfo": {
              "colorFamilies": [
                "Mixed"
              ],
              "colors": [
                "Bleu / Do The Rump"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "projects/100575538996/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/branches/0/products/829241429175635302",
            "id": "829241429175635302",
            "type": "VARIANT",
            "colorInfo": {
              "colorFamilies": [
                "Mixed"
              ],
              "colors": [
                "Bleu / Do The Rump"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "projects/100575538996/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/branches/0/products/829241429191888224",
            "id": "829241429191888224",
            "type": "VARIANT",
            "colorInfo": {
              "colorFamilies": [
                "Mixed"
              ],
              "colors": [
                "Bleu / Do The Rump"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "projects/100575538996/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/branches/0/products/829241429191888226",
            "id": "829241429191888226",
            "type": "VARIANT",
            "colorInfo": {
              "colorFamilies": [
                "Mixed"
              ],
              "colors": [
                "Bleu / Do The Rump"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "projects/100575538996/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/branches/0/products/829241429191888230",
            "id": "829241429191888230",
            "type": "VARIANT",
            "colorInfo": {
              "colorFamilies": [
                "Mixed"
              ],
              "colors": [
                "Bleu / Do The Rump"
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "matchingVariantCount": 28
    },
    {
      "id": "005010165",
      "product": {
        "name": "projects/100575538996/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/branches/0/products/005010165",
        "variants": [
          {
            "name": "projects/100575538996/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/branches/0/products/805308084680159867",
            "id": "805308084680159867",
            "type": "VARIANT",
            "colorInfo": {
              "colorFamilies": [
                "Mixed"
              ],
              "colors": [
                "Noir / Stonewashed Black"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "projects/100575538996/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/branches/0/products/805308084680159869",
            "id": "805308084680159869",
            "type": "VARIANT",
            "colorInfo": {
              "colorFamilies": [
                "Mixed"
              ],
              "colors": [
                "Noir / Stonewashed Black"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "projects/100575538996/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/branches/0/products/805308084680290937",
            "id": "805308084680290937",
            "type": "VARIANT",
            "colorInfo": {
              "colorFamilies": [
                "Mixed"
              ],
              "colors": [
                "Noir / Stonewashed Black"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "projects/100575538996/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/branches/0/products/805308084713190011",
            "id": "805308084713190011",
            "type": "VARIANT",
            "colorInfo": {
              "colorFamilies": [
                "Mixed"
              ],
              "colors": [
                "Noir / Stonewashed Black"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "projects/100575538996/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/branches/0/products/805308084713190013",
            "id": "805308084713190013",
            "type": "VARIANT",
            "colorInfo": {
              "colorFamilies": [
                "Mixed"
              ],
              "colors": [
                "Noir / Stonewashed Black"
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "matchingVariantCount": 35
    },
    {
      "id": "005010193",
      "product": {
        "name": "projects/100575538996/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/branches/0/products/005010193",
        "variants": [
          {
            "name": "projects/100575538996/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/branches/0/products/802205262917038717",
            "id": "802205262917038717",
            "type": "VARIANT",
            "colorInfo": {
              "colorFamilies": [
                "Mixed"
              ],
              "colors": [
                "Bleu / Medium Stonewash"
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "matchingVariantCount": 1
    },
    {
      "id": "005013261",
      "product": {
        "name": "projects/100575538996/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/branches/0/products/005013261",
        "variants": [
          {
            "name": "projects/100575538996/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/branches/0/products/616156075712646496",
            "id": "616156075712646496",
            "type": "VARIANT",
            "colorInfo": {
              "colorFamilies": [
                "Mixed"
              ],
              "colors": [
                "Bleu / Ska Ska"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "projects/100575538996/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/branches/0/products/616156075712646502",
            "id": "616156075712646502",
            "type": "VARIANT",
            "colorInfo": {
              "colorFamilies": [
                "Mixed"
              ],
              "colors": [
                "Bleu / Ska Ska"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "projects/100575538996/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/branches/0/products/616156075728899424",
            "id": "616156075728899424",
            "type": "VARIANT",
            "colorInfo": {
              "colorFamilies": [
                "Mixed"
              ],
              "colors": [
                "Bleu / Ska Ska"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "projects/100575538996/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/branches/0/products/616156075728899426",
            "id": "616156075728899426",
            "type": "VARIANT",
            "colorInfo": {
              "colorFamilies": [
                "Mixed"
              ],
              "colors": [
                "Bleu / Ska Ska"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "projects/100575538996/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/branches/0/products/616156075728899430",
            "id": "616156075728899430",
            "type": "VARIANT",
            "colorInfo": {
              "colorFamilies": [
                "Mixed"
              ],
              "colors": [
                "Bleu / Ska Ska"
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "matchingVariantCount": 24
    },
    {
      "id": "005010114",
      "product": {
        "name": "projects/100575538996/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/branches/0/products/005010114",
        "variants": [
          {
            "name": "projects/100575538996/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/branches/0/products/804462560238269051",
            "id": "804462560238269051",
            "type": "VARIANT",
            "colorInfo": {
              "colorFamilies": [
                "Mixed"
              ],
              "colors": [
                "Bleu / Stonewash"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "projects/100575538996/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/branches/0/products/804462560238400119",
            "id": "804462560238400119",
            "type": "VARIANT",
            "colorInfo": {
              "colorFamilies": [
                "Mixed"
              ],
              "colors": [
                "Bleu / Stonewash"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "projects/100575538996/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/branches/0/products/804462560238400121",
            "id": "804462560238400121",
            "type": "VARIANT",
            "colorInfo": {
              "colorFamilies": [
                "Mixed"
              ],
              "colors": [
                "Bleu / Stonewash"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "projects/100575538996/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/branches/0/products/804462560238400123",
            "id": "804462560238400123",
            "type": "VARIANT",
            "colorInfo": {
              "colorFamilies": [
                "Mixed"
              ],
              "colors": [
                "Bleu / Stonewash"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "projects/100575538996/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/branches/0/products/804462560238400125",
            "id": "804462560238400125",
            "type": "VARIANT",
            "colorInfo": {
              "colorFamilies": [
                "Mixed"
              ],
              "colors": [
                "Bleu / Stonewash"
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "matchingVariantCount": 39
    },
    {
      "id": "005010000",
      "product": {
        "name": "projects/100575538996/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/branches/0/products/005010000",
        "variants": [
          {
            "name": "projects/100575538996/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/branches/0/products/732682043130671739",
            "id": "732682043130671739",
            "type": "VARIANT",
            "colorInfo": {
              "colorFamilies": [
                "Mixed"
              ],
              "colors": [
                "Bleu / Rigid Stf"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "projects/100575538996/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/branches/0/products/732682043130671741",
            "id": "732682043130671741",
            "type": "VARIANT",
            "colorInfo": {
              "colorFamilies": [
                "Mixed"
              ],
              "colors": [
                "Bleu / Rigid Stf"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "projects/100575538996/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/branches/0/products/732682043163701885",
            "id": "732682043163701885",
            "type": "VARIANT",
            "colorInfo": {
              "colorFamilies": [
                "Mixed"
              ],
              "colors": [
                "Bleu / Rigid Stf"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "projects/100575538996/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/branches/0/products/732682043163767421",
            "id": "732682043163767421",
            "type": "VARIANT",
            "colorInfo": {
              "colorFamilies": [
                "Mixed"
              ],
              "colors": [
                "Bleu / Rigid Stf"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "projects/100575538996/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/branches/0/products/732682043180479099",
            "id": "732682043180479099",
            "type": "VARIANT",
            "colorInfo": {
              "colorFamilies": [
                "Mixed"
              ],
              "colors": [
                "Bleu / Rigid Stf"
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "matchingVariantCount": 28
    },
    {
      "id": "005010162",
      "product": {
        "name": "projects/100575538996/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/branches/0/products/005010162",
        "variants": [
          {
            "name": "projects/100575538996/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/branches/0/products/805300388098765435",
            "id": "805300388098765435",
            "type": "VARIANT",
            "colorInfo": {
              "colorFamilies": [
                "Mixed"
              ],
              "colors": [
                "Bleu / Marlon"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "projects/100575538996/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/branches/0/products/805300388098765437",
            "id": "805300388098765437",
            "type": "VARIANT",
            "colorInfo": {
              "colorFamilies": [
                "Mixed"
              ],
              "colors": [
                "Bleu / Marlon"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "projects/100575538996/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/branches/0/products/805300388131795581",
            "id": "805300388131795581",
            "type": "VARIANT",
            "colorInfo": {
              "colorFamilies": [
                "Mixed"
              ],
              "colors": [
                "Bleu / Marlon"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "projects/100575538996/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/branches/0/products/805300388131861115",
            "id": "805300388131861115",
            "type": "VARIANT",
            "colorInfo": {
              "colorFamilies": [
                "Mixed"
              ],
              "colors": [
                "Bleu / Marlon"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "projects/100575538996/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/branches/0/products/805300388131861117",
            "id": "805300388131861117",
            "type": "VARIANT",
            "colorInfo": {
              "colorFamilies": [
                "Mixed"
              ],
              "colors": [
                "Bleu / Marlon"
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "matchingVariantCount": 29
    },
    {
      "id": "005013220",
      "product": {
        "name": "projects/100575538996/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/branches/0/products/005013220",
        "variants": [
          {
            "name": "projects/100575538996/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/branches/0/products/615031275317431648",
            "id": "615031275317431648",
            "type": "VARIANT",
            "colorInfo": {
              "colorFamilies": [
                "Mixed"
              ],
              "colors": [
                "Bleu / Indigo Mask"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "projects/100575538996/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/branches/0/products/615031275317431654",
            "id": "615031275317431654",
            "type": "VARIANT",
            "colorInfo": {
              "colorFamilies": [
                "Mixed"
              ],
              "colors": [
                "Bleu / Indigo Mask"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "projects/100575538996/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/branches/0/products/615031275317562726",
            "id": "615031275317562726",
            "type": "VARIANT",
            "colorInfo": {
              "colorFamilies": [
                "Mixed"
              ],
              "colors": [
                "Bleu / Indigo Mask"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "projects/100575538996/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/branches/0/products/615031275333684576",
            "id": "615031275333684576",
            "type": "VARIANT",
            "colorInfo": {
              "colorFamilies": [
                "Mixed"
              ],
              "colors": [
                "Bleu / Indigo Mask"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "projects/100575538996/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/branches/0/products/615031275333684578",
            "id": "615031275333684578",
            "type": "VARIANT",
            "colorInfo": {
              "colorFamilies": [
                "Mixed"
              ],
              "colors": [
                "Bleu / Indigo Mask"
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "matchingVariantCount": 30
    },
    {
      "id": "005010101",
      "product": {
        "name": "projects/100575538996/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/branches/0/products/005010101",
        "variants": [
          {
            "name": "projects/100575538996/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/branches/0/products/804740736680227451",
            "id": "804740736680227451",
            "type": "VARIANT",
            "colorInfo": {
              "colorFamilies": [
                "Mixed"
              ],
              "colors": [
                "Bleu / One Wash"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "projects/100575538996/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/branches/0/products/804740736680227453",
            "id": "804740736680227453",
            "type": "VARIANT",
            "colorInfo": {
              "colorFamilies": [
                "Mixed"
              ],
              "colors": [
                "Bleu / One Wash"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "projects/100575538996/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/branches/0/products/804740736713257595",
            "id": "804740736713257595",
            "type": "VARIANT",
            "colorInfo": {
              "colorFamilies": [
                "Mixed"
              ],
              "colors": [
                "Bleu / One Wash"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "projects/100575538996/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/branches/0/products/804740736713257597",
            "id": "804740736713257597",
            "type": "VARIANT",
            "colorInfo": {
              "colorFamilies": [
                "Mixed"
              ],
              "colors": [
                "Bleu / One Wash"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "projects/100575538996/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/branches/0/products/804740736713257599",
            "id": "804740736713257599",
            "type": "VARIANT",
            "colorInfo": {
              "colorFamilies": [
                "Mixed"
              ],
              "colors": [
                "Bleu / One Wash"
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "matchingVariantCount": 40
    },
    {
      "id": "005013108",
      "product": {
        "name": "projects/100575538996/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/branches/0/products/005013108",
        "variants": [
          {
            "name": "projects/100575538996/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/branches/0/products/831775803477658976",
            "id": "831775803477658976",
            "type": "VARIANT",
            "colorInfo": {
              "colorFamilies": [
                "Mixed"
              ],
              "colors": [
                "Bleu / Basil Sand"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "projects/100575538996/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/branches/0/products/831775803477658982",
            "id": "831775803477658982",
            "type": "VARIANT",
            "colorInfo": {
              "colorFamilies": [
                "Mixed"
              ],
              "colors": [
                "Bleu / Basil Sand"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "projects/100575538996/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/branches/0/products/831775803493911904",
            "id": "831775803493911904",
            "type": "VARIANT",
            "colorInfo": {
              "colorFamilies": [
                "Mixed"
              ],
              "colors": [
                "Bleu / Basil Sand"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "projects/100575538996/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/branches/0/products/831775803493911906",
            "id": "831775803493911906",
            "type": "VARIANT",
            "colorInfo": {
              "colorFamilies": [
                "Mixed"
              ],
              "colors": [
                "Bleu / Basil Sand"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "projects/100575538996/locations/global/catalogs/default_catalog/branches/0/products/831775803493911910",
            "id": "831775803493911910",
            "type": "VARIANT",
            "colorInfo": {
              "colorFamilies": [
                "Mixed"
              ],
              "colors": [
                "Bleu / Basil Sand"
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "matchingVariantCount": 28
    }
  ],
  "totalSize": 10,
  "attributionToken": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

I want to get more product informations

Comment: thanks for this question - this literally cost me several hours... I just switched "Retrievable" on, I guess I have to wait a bit for it to take effect...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to modify site-wide attribute controls
set Retrievable to true

[setting of attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVlHG.png)

ref: https://cloud.google.com/retail/docs/manage-site-controls